# Simplest way to solve this system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Please help me to find solution of the system of equations for `a`, `x` and `y`:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
a = \frac{3x^2}{2y} \\
b = a^2 - 2x \\
c = a(x-b)-y
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Wolfram Alpha gave this [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:a%3D(3*x%5E2)%2F(2*y),+b%3Da%5E2-2*x,+c%3Da*(x-b)-y%2F%2F%5D%7D,+%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:a,+x,+y%2F%2F%5D%7D%5D).

But may be there is simpliest way to get `a`, `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the second equation we get $$x=\frac{1}{2}(a^2-b)$$ plugging this in the third equation we obtain
$$y=a(\frac{1}{2}(a^2-b))-c$$
simplifying this we get
$$y=\frac{1}{2}(a^3-3ab-2c)$$ inserting both in the first equation we get a condition
$$a=\frac{3\left(\frac{1}{2}(a^2-b)\right)^2}{a^3-3ab-2c}$$
simplifying this we have
$$a^4+14a^2b-8ac-27b^2=0$$ and $$a^3-ab-2c\ne 0$$
using this new Information we get the following equation for $$a$$
$$a^4-6a^2b-8ac-3b^2=0$$

Comment: i'am sorry, but im my task "a" is unknown too. i'am sorry and now try to edit my question

Comment: is there any way to escape from 4-th degree polynom?

Comment: i'm sorry i think no

Comment: it's a pitty, but needs to do it without 4-th degree polynom

Comment: i think this is iompossble if you Additionally want to know $a$

Answer (score 2):

Well, using the second equation we get:

$$\text{b}=\text{a}^2-2x\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{\text{a}^2-\text{b}}{2}\tag1$$

And using the third:

$$\text{c}=\text{a}\left(x-\text{b}\right)-\text{y}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{y}=\text{a}\left(x-\text{b}\right)-\text{c}\tag2$$

So, substitute that into the first equation:

$$\text{a}=\frac{3x^2}{2\text{y}}=\frac{3\left(\frac{\text{a}^2-\text{b}}{2}\right)^2}{2\left(\text{a}\left(\frac{\text{a}^2-\text{b}}{2}-\text{b}\right)-\text{c}\right)}\tag3$$

Answer (score 1):

From the second equation, one has 
$$x=\frac12(a^2-b).$$
From the first equation, one has 
$$y=\frac{3x^2}{2a}=\frac3{8a}(a^2-b)^2.$$
Replacing $x,y$ in the third equation, one can see that $a,b,c$ has to satisfiy
$$ c=a(\frac12(a^2-b)-b)-\frac3{8a}(a^2-b)^2 $$
or
$$ 8ac=4a^2(a^2-3b)-3(a^2-b)^2.$$

Comment: I need to find x and y

Comment: @Denis, $x,y$ are there.